# Databricks: dataframe add multiple columns into one columns

Tags: dataframe, databricks

Suppose I am going to add two columns into one columns
df
col1  col2   col3
1     2      3
3     4      5

and add a columns
col1  col2   col3     SUM 
1     2      3        6
3     4      5        12

df.withColumn("SUM", col(col1) + col(col2) + col(col3))

but I would like to do dynamically :

array=["col1","col2","col3"]

df.withColumn("SUM", *[col(x) for x in colarray])

but seems I am not sure where I can place a plus '+' over there.

Comment: anyone has the idea ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
val colList = df.schema.fields.map(struct=> col(struct.name))
val newDf = df.withColumn("Sum",colList.reduce(_+_))
```

This is the generic Commands:

1. The first command is used to get a list of all columns from the Dataframe.
2. The second command is used to create new DF with a new column name `Sum` which has sum of all the columns.

Comment: can I do in pyspark ?
colist=["col1","col2"]
newdf=df.withColumn("Sum",colist.reduce(_+_))

Comment: Yes, you can do same in pyspark.

Comment: I have got the error :
 'list' object has no attribute 'reduce'